# How to format most recently clicked link

Tags: css, hyperlink

I am wondering if it's possible to format only the most recently clicked link so that I can use it to show which page the user is on? My code currently looks like this:
e- loa

```
.topbar a:link {color:#999}
.topbar a:visited {color:#999;}
.topbar a:hover { color:#666;}
.topbar a:active {color:#CCC;}
```

Ideally I'd like the active link to stay active when the page it's linking to loads so that the link is a lighter colour to show users which page they're on, but obviously this isn't possible. I'd love any suggestions for a better way of doing it too, no doubt there are loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no work around with CSS. You need to define in the markup what link is active. For example:

```
<nav class="topbar">
  <a href="1.html" class="active"></li>
  <a href="2.html"></li>
  <a href="3.html"></li>
</nav>
```

You have to do this in the markup itself and then create a style such as this:

```
.topbar a.active {color:#red;}
```

You could also accomplish the class on that link by using a bit of javascript. This could find out the page you are on and add the class to that specific link element.

The :active selector only defines the style for the moment you have pressed on the link. It's kind of like a Button Pressed Down style. It's nice to give user feedback that a link was actually clicked and gives a nice touch. But it will not highlight the link that has been recently clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript if you maintain your link on the same page as the information being displayed. I have a page with two iframes. Clicking the link in the left iframe displays the appropriate page on the right. The links are rows in a table

Each row has a `class="clickable"`

I added an additional class called `last-clicked` with JavaScript when the link clicked on the left is currently displayed on the right. This will highlight the row, so the user know which row is being displayed on the right.

I remove the prior highlighted row first to ensure only the most current link is clicked. The JavaScript basically does the following:

1. Continuous looks for one of the `clickable` rows to receive a click
2. Once a click is registered, it loops through all the `clickable` rows and removes the class `last-clicked`
3. Then it returns back to the original loop and adds the class `last-clicked` to the proper row.

Here is the code and you can test it below.

```js
let clickables=document.getElementsByClassName('clickable');
for (const i of clickables) {
   i.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for(const j of clickables) {
      j.classList.remove('last-clicked');
    }
    i.classList.add('last-clicked');
   });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
  width: 75px;
}
tr {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.clickable:active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.last-clicked {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<table >
<tr class="clickable"><td>Values</td><td>And</td><td>Things</td></tr>
<tr class="clickable"><td>Values</td><td>And</td><td>Things</td></tr>
<tr class="clickable"><td>Values</td><td>And</td><td>Things</td></tr>
<tr class="clickable"><td>Values</td><td>And</td><td>Things</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```